# How to protect a file while still allowing file_put_contents to append it?

Tags: php, security, file-put-contents

Let's assume you have a blog with user registration and for various reasons you decide to keep some of the less important user information in a file. You use `file_put_contents` to create and then append the file. Obviously you still want to protect it somehow.

Protecting it from people who don't have access to the server should be fairly easy. You use .php extension instead of .txt, comment out the contents, put `die()` at the beginning of the file or better still - place it in a directory inaccessible from the web (above your website root directory).

My question is: **how do you protect the file from people who might already have or acquire the access to the server, while still allowing `file_put_contents` to append the file?**

Any ideas how to approach this issue? Encryption? Password protection? Both of these solutions would require you to put key/password in a file where the function is. You could get key/password from database, which adds the extra layer of security but still, it's not a perfect solution.

Comment: If someone has access to your server, you're screwed anyway.

Comment: Also if you're using plain .txt files, just add the rule `RewriteRule \.txt$ - [F]` to your `.htaccess` to deny access from the web. But you should really use a database.

Comment: If someone has access to your server, they can do anything your server can do, and if your server needs to be able to read that file… well…

Comment: If you give normal users access to your host each with their own username then you can just ensure that the file belongs to the webserver user (e.g. www-data) and is not readable or writable by others (permissions 600) .